# How to get selected check box value to a variable in script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html form content with two check boxes like

```
<p class="text">
                <input type="checkbox" value="Yes" id="ques11" name="radiobutton" class="option_1" />
                <label for="ques11">True</label>
                <span class="hide" id="ans1">Answer: True</span>
                <span id="rite11" class="hide"><img class="imgsize" src="images/ans_correct.png"/></span>
                <span id="wrong11" class="hide"><img class="imgsize" src="images/ans_wrong.png"/></span> </p>

            <p class="text">
                <input type="checkbox" value="No" id="ques12" name="radiobutton" class="option_2" />
                <label for="ques12">False</label>
                <span id="rite12" class="hide"><img class="imgsize" src="images/ans_correct.png"/></span>
                <span id="wrong12" class="hide"><img class="imgsize" src="images/ans_wrong.png"/></span> </p>
```

for this  i have written code to get the checkboxes

```
   $(function(){
    $('#_submit').on('click', function(){
     completedata = 'selected_';
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){

   var quesNo = $(this).closest("div[id^='questionsNo_']").attr('id').split('_');
 var chapterId = quesNo[1]; 
 var questionId = quesNo[2];
 var optionId = $(this).attr('class').split('_')[1];
var currentAns = $(this).val();
 completedata += 'choose'+','+chapterId + ',' + questionId + ',' + optionId + ',' + currentAns + '_';
  completedata = completedata.substr(0, completedata.length - 1) + '_selectedEnd';
  if(completedata == "selected_selectedEnd"){

          document.getElementById("selids").innerHTML="";
  }

    else {
        $('#selids').text(completedata);
                 }
```

In this line i have to get which checkbox is checked, how to get that using this script. Please help me how to do that.

```
 var optionId = $(this).attr('class').split('_')[1];
```

i want which check box is clicked  based on  class="option_1"  or class="option_2".

Comment: `$('.'+ optionId).val()`

Comment: You can refer this link : http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-check-a-checkbox-is-checked-or-not-using-jquery.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("input[name='radiobutton']").click(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
{
    // checked
}
else
{
   // unchecked
}
});
```